# Can't get .getwidth() and .getheight() to work

Tags: java, android, height, width

I know there have been a lot of other questions on this topic, but I've looked through all of them, and still not gotten it to work.

I've made this code for testing:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

RelativeLayout layout;
TextView widthtext;
TextView heighttext;
int width;
int height;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rela);

    widthtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    heighttext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    layout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            width = layout.getWidth();
            height = layout.getHeight();
        }
    });

    widthtext.setText(width);
    heighttext.setText(height);
}
```

and

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/rela">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="123"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="123"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

After a lot of hassle I've now notised that the width and height int's have the right values, though I can't make them display in my TextViews, getting the NullPointerExeption.

Anyone who can make this work?

EXTRA:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

RelativeLayout layout;
TextView widthtext;
TextView heighttext;
int width;
int height;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rela);

    widthtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    heighttext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    layout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            width = layout.getWidth();
            height = layout.getHeight();
        }
    });

    widthtext.setText(width + "");
    heighttext.setText(height + "");
}
```

}

Comment: are you sure it is a NPE? try converting the int in string before passing it to the setText. E.g   `widthtext.setText("""+width);` andd
    `heighttext.setText(""+height);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing this

```
widthtext.setText(width);
heighttext.setText(height);
```

outside of your listener so naturally it doesn't have the values yet.

Move them inside

```
layout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        width = layout.getWidth();
        height = layout.getHeight();

        // move here
        widthtext.setText(width);
        heighttext.setText(height);
    }
});
}
```

As [blackbelt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501696/blackbelt) pointed out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28796676/cant-get-getwidth-and-getheight-to-work?nah=1#comment45867838_28796731), you are calling [`setText()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)) and passing an `int`. This will look for a resource id of that value. Change those to `Strings`.

```
widthtext.setText("" + width);
heighttext.setText("" + height);
```

Comment: orb, be aware. int width, int height

Comment: Thanks. bor @Blackbelt will fix

Comment: That is what I tried first, but then the application crashed. Is still doing this.

Comment: See the update. If it crashes with that then you need to edit your post with the logcat

Comment: Strange, now I it sets the values to 0 and 0 again, and can't get it back to when it managed to measure the right values. Will post the logcat in 2 sec.

Comment: well at least it doesn't crash :D

Comment: Ok, now it shows 0 and 0, without crashing. So what can I do to make it show the real width and height of the layout?

Comment: Post the updated code you have in your OP without removing the original code you posted

Comment: Posted in the original question

Comment: put   widthtext.setText(width + "");
    heighttext.setText(height + ""); in onGlobalLayout after you retrieve width and height

Comment: THANKS blackbelt, works!!!! sorry for Caps Lock and Exlamtions marks, but that was awesome! please post it as an answer

Comment: @codeMagic posted already an answer. Press on *his* check mark

Comment: Still one problem; I need to use the values we get from the .getwidth and .getheight in another class. You know how to do that?

Comment: Pass them through an Intent.

Comment: tried to do that, but it didn't allow me to set up an intent inside the onGlobal Layout, and it didn't even work when I sat it up inside a method called from the onGlobalLayout

Comment: Ok, finnaly maneged to make it work :) Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

`setText` takes string value

so instead of

```
setText(width);
setText(height);
```

do

```
setText(width+"");
setText(height+"");
```